# Jquery validate message showing inside the text input in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm pretty new to jQuery mobile, I'm using jQuery Validate plugin for forms control validation, everything working fine, but the validation message shows along with the input text box.  Here is the image:

[image: Image of validation warnings next to inputs]

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).live('pageinit', function (e) {
     $('#form1').validate({             
         submitHandler: function (form) {
             $.mobile.changePage('#success', { transition: "slide" });
             return false; 
         }
     });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="fname" data-theme="d">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
        <br />
    </div>           
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="lname" data-theme="d">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="email" data-theme="d">E-mail Address:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QAePU/2/)

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.error{
    color:red;
    display:block; //to show error message in new line
}
```

---

Updated After OP's comment

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QAePU/4/)

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().after());
},
```

another way [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QAePU/3/)

Reference

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: I added the code "             errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                 error.appendTo(element.prev());
             }," before submitHandler function, now its not showing the messages

Comment: Thanks, I missed the parent, right? by the way, how to make the message below of the textbox?

Comment: still the message coming under the label not text box.is it possible to make below of text box?

Comment: Better Use `errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().after());
},` . It not work for you as i added span tag in html after every textbox .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following code for **JQM 1.4**:

```
error.appendTo(element.closest('.ui-field-contain'));
```